# SharePoint search results by date, descending

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint search results page using federated search results web part that I want to display latest results. I have it set up to spit out results based on date modified but I would like to display the results by modified date descending.

Also, is it possible to leverage another column for sorting?

Comment: what version of SharePoint?

Comment: 2010 - sorry, forgot to mention that.